# Trying to get text from website and display it in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Ok I have an exsiting app that I am currently working on an update for. What I am trying to do is when the client updates their website, the app will pull the text from the certain page and display the text in an UITextView? I am trying this approach which works fine except it includes the text of the NavBar? So how do I get the text only and no NavBar?

```
   textView.text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have two choices from the point i see it at. If you know how long the text in the nav bar is and it is the same character length just use:

```
NSString *webString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
int length = amount of characters to remove from beginning of string;
webString = [webString substringFromIndex:length];
```

If you dont know the amount you want to remove you can use the NSScanner which is a bit more complicated but is more flexible.

```
NSString *webString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

[stringScanner scanUpToString:@"Start of the text you want" intoString:null];
[stringScanner scanUpToString:@"End of the text you want" intoString:&content];
}
```

Hope This Helps :D

Comment: Ok I know what you are telling me works but just not for me... yet. When I try to use the first option i keep getting 'Range or index out of bounds'? And on the second one nothing happens everything is still showing up, header and all?

Comment: Could you add the string you want to edit and what you want to be removed... the error you are recieving is because you are trying to remove more characters than there are in the string, hense out of the bounds of the characters indexpath.

Comment: Here is the link of the page I am working with. What I am trying to get is just the text of the page, but when I pull it I also get the text of the navigation bar at the top of the page. So what I want is all the text below the bar starting with, "Andalee's Academy of BellyDance"?  http://andalee.com/andalee/CLASSES.html Any more help would be awesome? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out... kind of. I got the text I want by using document.getElementsByClassName('graphic_textbox_layout_style_default')[0].innerText" this got the right text but the problem Im having now is these tags right here<p style="padding-top: 0pt; " class="Body"><br /></p>
                <p class="Body"><br /></p>
                <p class="Body"><br /></p> These are right after my div tag starts just to create some space on the webpage. Is there a way that I can skip over these three lines? So I can remove the empty space at the top of my view?

Comment: Thank you it works perfect now!!! I had the owner of the website change how it was structured and it works perfect!!!

Comment: Sound Ggreat that you got it sorted out, sorry for not answering in a while.... hope there arent any more issues :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am trying to use

```
NSString *webString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText"];
NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];
while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"Andalee" intoString:NULL];
    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"Eastern Sun Dance Company Rehearsal Mondays 7:00pm @ Cal Arts Academy" intoString:&content];
    textView.text = webString; }
```

Maybe I am approaching it wrong.
Here is the webpage that I am trying to pull from http://andalee.com/andalee/CLASSES.html